# html5 microdata mixed with other new semantic elements. Is this correct?

Tags: html, microdata

I am writing markup for a restaurant review. This is what I’ve got so far:

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review">
    <img src="" alt="Shatranj Napoli" />

    <h3 itemprop="itemreviewed">
        <a href="">
            <strong>Shatranj Napoli </strong>
            <em>Bandra West</em>
        </a>
    </h3>

    <p class="cuisine">Italian &amp; Lucknowi</p>

    <p itemprop="summary">Whoa! What a marriage of cuisines! Italian and Lucknowi. And much to my surprise, both are good, though I prefer...</p>

    <span itemprop="rating">4.5</span>

    <span class="price-rating">3.5</spam>
</article>
```

Does this look right? Or will this not work at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine to me, as per [Google’s documentation](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146645).

I don’t think the fact that you’re using the `<article>` tag will cause any problems, at least as far as the microdata goes — see e.g. http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/extensibility.html#data-model, where `<section>` is used in the example.

Comment: I am using article because these are part of a series of entries. Hence, articles. What do you think?

Comment: @Amit: sounds like correct use of the `<article>` tag to me, and using microdata on an article tag should (judging from the links above) be fine too.